# Amazon like sort box on taxonomy page

Tags: nodes, taxonomy-terms

I have a taxonomy term page that lists certain nodes. I would like to include custom sort options like the one on amazon's search results page, at the top. It is a drop down with sort options, unlike the usual clicking on a table column. I have searched but found no resources on implementing this in drupal. Any ideas on how I can implement this?
Thx

Answer (score 1):

The most easy way to get this taken care of is use the [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) module. Set up a view that queries for nodes based on the term as an argument. This will give you what you already have, however, it will also allow you to use exposed filters to get more granular with the results based on the values of the exposed fields.

If you would like to learn more about exposed filteds and views, check out [this video](http://yadadrop.com/drupal-video/drupal-views-exposed-filter-1), which is not the best video in the world, but highlights using exposed filters in Views, which should hopefully get you on the right track.

As a summary, what your doing is replacing Drupal's built in taxonomy view pages with a view instead and allowing views to handle the querying and filtration of the data respectively.

Happy Programming!

Comment: Hmm....I understand the view part, but how do I hook these views up to a drop down list. And is it possible to ajaxify the requests?